# CSS overflow scroll and visible at same time

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have scrollable div with child div. Is there any way to show whole child (also outside of scrollable div)? Now, `overflow-x: scroll` is like `overflow-x: hidden` with scrollbar. I would like `overflow-x: visible` with scrollbar. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91ejr703/2/).

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, green);
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
}

.containerExample {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, green);
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
  width: 600px;
}

.childExample {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
Now:

<div class="container">
<div class="child">

</div>
</div>

What I want (red border should be scrollable div):

<div class="containerExample">
<div class="childExample">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want this red div to be movable?

Answer (score 2):

You could use some js here to clone the child element and then use `scroll` event on the `container` to calculate the horizontal scroll and use the same value to offset the position of the cloned element.

```js
const container = $(".container")
const child = container.find('.child');
const clone = child.clone();
const border = 4;

clone.addClass('clone');
child.addClass('transparent');
container.css('border-width', border);
container.before(clone)

$(".container").on('scroll', function() {
  const offset = $(this).scrollLeft() - border;
  clone.css({
    left: -offset
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid red;
  z-index: 10;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, green);
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.transparent {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this because it's a problem I keep re-writing myself so this is both for you and me as a reminder of how it works :)

It's in bootstrap but you can copy the styles and just use it for your own CSS

A horizontally scrollable "carousel" style row with no scrollbars

```css
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid overflow-scroll">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-visible">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-primary">asdfafd
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="bg-light">asd
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-light">asdfa
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="bg-light">asdfaf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This technique won't work for all use cases, but it does for your example. Since scroll content is visible in the padding area, I add a padding of the same size as the space between the viewport and the element and then push it the same amount back to the left.

```css
.width {
  width: 500px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-inline: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 100%) / -2);
}

.content {
  width: 200vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="width">
  I'm normal
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  And I'm here too
</div>
```

Hope this helps!